# PHP Callback function not working on object functions

Tags: php, arrays, oop, callback

I have an array and want to apply `MySQLi->real_escape_string` on every member of the array through `array_walk` but this is not working:

```
array_walk($array, '$mysqli->real_escape_string');
```

It gives this error:

> Warning: array_walk() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback, function '$mysqli->real_escape_string' not found or invalid function name in C:\wamp\www\ts.php on line 69

`$mysqli` is a valid object and works fine if I do `$mysqli->real_escape_string('anything')` on anything else.

**My Question:** Is it not possible to pass object's functions as callback ? Or am I doing something wrong.

---

**IMPORTANT:** I know I can create my own callback function and implement $mysqli->real_escape_string in it *BUT* I want to know is it not possible to use callback as an object's function ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you can read on [php callback](http://php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php) page, you shall use:

```
# produces an error
array_walk($array, array($msqli, 'real_escape_string'));
array_map($array, array($msqli, 'real_escape_string'));
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. It says: `Warning: array_walk() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback, non-static method mysqli::real_escape_string() cannot be called statically`

Comment: That was with quotes and when using EXACTLY how you wrote, it says: `Warning: mysqli::real_escape_string() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given`

Comment: With array_map, it seems to work (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php#63279)

Answer (score 11):

If your calling a method within an object you should pass in an array, first item being the object / context and then second should be the method:

Small example

```
function callback()
{
   //blah
}
```

the above is called a function and should be called like so: `array_walk($array, 'callback');`

```
class object()
{
    public function callback()
    {
    }
}
```

the above callback is called a method, its practically the same as a function but because its within a class it has a parent context, so should be called like so:

```
$object = new object();
array_walk($array, array($object , 'callback'));
```

MySQLi is an object orientated library so after you have initialized your mysqli object you should call the "method" like so:

```
array_walk($array, array($msqli, 'real_escape_string'));
```

Also as mentioned above, `array_walk` will walk both key and value into the mysql object witch will cause in exact escaping, you should use `array_map` to walk the values alone:

`array_map($array, array($msqli, 'real_escape_string'));`

Answer (score 0):

array_walk will only allow a user defined function to be passed as the callback, not a core PHP function or method. To do this I would try the following:

```
foreach($array as &$value) {
    $value = $mysqli->real_escape_string($value);
}
```

Passing the value by reference allows it to be modified within the foreach loop, resulting in each member of the array being escaped.

Comment: I know I can do that. I am just asking is there no way to pass non-static methods ?

Comment: The problem is with array_walk as it can only be used with a user defined function or method. Try array_map as Aif suggests, passing the object and method name as an array as Aif also suggests.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this post](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php#115622) to be quite useful when figuring out how to get `array_walk()` to work in methods within a class.  Adding it to this thread in case it helps others out.