# Error with array_walk_recursive and mysqli::real_escape_string

Tags: php, mysql

I use object oriented style for my mysql connection, but if I write this:

```
array_walk_recursive($_POST, array($mysqli, 'real_escape_string'));
```

I get this error:

```
Warning: mysqli::real_escape_string() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given
```

The fact is that **mysqli::escape_string** accept **only 1 parameter**:

```
string mysqli::escape_string ( string $escapestr )
```

---

I write:

```
$VAR = array();
$VAR = $_POST;

function escape_string($item, $key) {
    $arr[$key] = $mysqli->real_escape_string($item);
}

array_walk_recursive($VAR, 'escape_string');
```

And I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function real_escape_string() on a non-object
```

Comment: In another post, someone used that exact syntax but with array_walk: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900920/php-callback-function-not-working-on-object-functions. I don't know why you're getting the error, but maybe the post will somehow help.

Comment: array_walk doesn't walk recursive in a multidimensional array.
array_walk_recursive does.

Comment: I know that, but I was pointing out that the syntax is exactly the same, so it's strange that you are getting that error. Even so, I thought there might be something that could help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a string as the second argument, not an array:

```
function escape_string($item, $key) {
    // Echo them out (using procedural mysqli)
    echo mysqli_real_escape_string($item);
    // or collect them in an array (using OOP mysqli)
    $arr[$key] = $mysqli->real_escape_string($item);
}

array_walk_recursive($_POST, 'escape_string');
```

Answer (score 1):

See the definition of [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php).

> Typically, funcname takes on two parameters. The input parameter's
>   value being the first, and the key/index second.

As you correctly point out:

> The fact is that mysqli::escape_string accept only 1 parameter:

So wrap `real_escape_string()` in a function that takes two parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to try `array_map` but recursive.

```
function array_map_recursive($fn, $arr) {
    $rarr = array();
    foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
        $rarr[$k] = is_array($v)
            ? array_map_recursive($fn, $v)
            : $fn($v); // or call_user_func($fn, $v)
    }
    return $rarr;
}
```

Here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php#107808

Or something like this (using with "ref");

```
function array_map_recursive2($fn, &$arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
        $arr[$k] = is_array($v)
            ? array_map_recursive2($fn, $v)
            : $fn($v);
    }
    return $arr;
}

$a = array(1,2,array(5,array(6)));
array_map_recursive2(function($v){
    return $v * 2;
}, $a);
print_r($a);
```

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 4
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 12
                )

        )

)
```